# tomcat based app heroku deploy error

Tags: java, heroku

i am trying to run an app on heroku platform but i'm getting this error always:

> 2016-10-09T23:21:08.554257+00:00 heroku[java.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2016-10-09T23:21:13.430590+00:00 heroku[java.1]: Starting process with command `$JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 44920 target/*.war`
>   2016-10-09T23:21:14.106864+00:00 heroku[java.1]: State changed from starting to up
>   2016-10-09T23:21:16.439714+00:00 app[java.1]: bash: -Xmx350m: command not found
>   2016-10-09T23:21:16.593417+00:00 heroku[java.1]: State changed from up to crashed
>   2016-10-09T23:21:16.585193+00:00 heroku[java.1]: Process exited with status 127

Can someone help me?

Comment: `-Xmx350m command not found` seems to be your problem right there. It's confusing the `Xmx` JVM flag with a command to run on bash, I imagine there's something wrong, either with the Procfile or with the JAVA_OPTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Procfile` does not contain the `java` command. It probably needs to look like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 44920 target/*.war
```

Comment: my procfile is exactly like that: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war

Comment: Does it have the `web:` at the front? Are all changes checked into git?

Comment: i had forgotten of "web:" before java :l